# NuGet - RID and TFM Examples

Tags: nuget, runtime-identifier

I've been reviewing the code for NuGet3 on GitHub, and I see several folder patterns in https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet3/blob/a5bc907d36ddaa8d4fa6c499e50d7ebf8993ed39/src/NuGet.Client/ManagedCodeConventions.cs related to expected folder structures within a NuGet package. However, I'm having a hard time finding any examples of these - specifically the rid and tfm values.

How can I know all the possible values for rid and tfm? I know they mean Runtime Identifier and Target Framework Moniker, but I don't really know what to do with that.

The documentation that I've seen never seems to deal with the topic directly or exhaustively.

Comment: Check [Supporting Multiple .NET Framework Versions and Profiles](http://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions). I think it partially answers your question, at least for the tfm part.

Answer (score 1):

The target frameworks are currently hard coded within the NuGet source code. Whilst some of the target frameworks are documented on the [NuGet website](http://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions) there are many which are not documented there. So as Jeff R already mentioned the best way to find the target frameworks is currently to look at the NuGet source code.

- [NuGet version 2 target frameworks](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.8.7/src/Core/Utility/VersionUtility.cs).
- [NuGet version 3 target frameworks](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/23ea68b91a439fcfd7f94bcd01bcdee2e8adae92/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/FrameworkConstants.cs)

NuGet also has [short identifiers](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/23ea68b91a439fcfd7f94bcd01bcdee2e8adae92/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs) for some of these frameworks (e.g. wp = WindowsPhone).

The runtime identifiers defined by Microsoft are available in the [Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms). Inside this NuGet package is a runtime.json file with the runtime identifiers:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "base": {
        },

        "any": {
            "#import": [ "base" ]
        },

        "win": {
            "#import": [ "any" ]
        },
        "win-x86": {
            "#import": [ "win" ]
        },
        "win-x64": {
            "#import": [ "win" ]
        },

        "win7": {
            "#import": [ "win" ]
        },
        "win7-x86": {
            "#import": [ "win7", "win-x86" ]
        },
        "win7-x64": {
            "#import": [ "win7", "win-x64" ]
        },

        "win8": {
            "#import": [ "win7" ]
        },
        "win8-x86": {
            "#import": [ "win8", "win7-x86" ]
        },
        "win8-x64": {
            "#import": [ "win8", "win7-x64" ]
        },
        "win8-arm": {
            "#import": [ "win8" ]
        },

        "win81": {
            "#import": [ "win8" ]
        },
        "win81-x86": {
            "#import": [ "win81", "win8-x86" ]
        },
        "win81-x64": {
            "#import": [ "win81", "win8-x64" ]
        },
        "win81-arm": {
            "#import": [ "win81", "win8-arm" ]
        },

        "win10": {
            "#import": [ "win81" ]
        },
        "win10-x86": {
            "#import": [ "win10", "win81-x86" ]
        },
        "win10-x64": {
            "#import": [ "win10", "win81-x64" ]
        },
        "win10-arm": {
            "#import": [ "win10", "win81-arm" ]
        },


        "aot": {
            "#import": [ "any" ]
        },

        "win-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win", "aot" ]
        },
        "win-x86-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win-aot", "win-x86" ]
        },
        "win-x64-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win-aot", "win-x64" ]
        },

        "win7-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win-aot", "win7" ]
        },
        "win7-x86-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win7-aot", "win7-x86" ]
        },
        "win7-x64-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win7-aot", "win7-x64" ]
        },

        "win8-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win8", "win7-aot" ]
        },
        "win8-x86-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win8-aot", "win8-x86", "win7-x86-aot" ]
        },
        "win8-x64-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win8-aot", "win8-x64", "win7-x64-aot" ]
        },
        "win8-arm-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win8-aot", "win8-arm" ]
        },

        "win81-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win81", "win8-aot" ]
        },
        "win81-x86-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win81-aot", "win81-x86", "win8-x86-aot" ]
        },
        "win81-x64-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win81-aot", "win81-x64", "win8-x64-aot" ]
        },
        "win81-arm-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win81-aot", "win81-arm", "win8-arm-aot" ]
        },

        "win10-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win10", "win81-aot" ]
        },
        "win10-x86-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win10-aot", "win10-x86", "win81-x86-aot" ]
        },
        "win10-x64-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win10-aot", "win10-x64", "win81-x64-aot" ]
        },
        "win10-arm-aot": {
            "#import": [ "win10-aot", "win10-arm", "win81-arm-aot" ]
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to review the docs and look at the code. Most of this answer comes from the code.

TargetFrameworkMoniker / tfm is constructed by using one of the constants from FrameworkIdentifiers in [FrameworkConstants.cs](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet3/blob/c8eacbec5209f1e5299c47e46ed1f46abe46144b/src/NuGet.Frameworks/FrameworkConstants.cs) . It is a framework identifier, plus a version concatenated on the end. Some examples include:

- net451 (.NET 4.5.1)
- dotnet (sort of a "current" tag for the latest .NET / portable class library)
- uap10.0 (Universal Windows Application, for version 10, the latest as of this post)
- native (for C/C++ code packaged using NuGet. Also take a look at CoApp if you intend to use this one)
- MonoTouch
- MonoAndroid
- Xamarin.iOS

Plus others you can find in the code linked above.

For runtime identifiers, they are composed of an operating system identifier of some sort, plus an architecture. So, in [JsonRuntimeFormatTests.cs](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet3/blob/0002affc8087784a18f8ed735c3ce7620e84b267/test/NuGet.RuntimeModel.Test/JsonRuntimeFormatTests.cs) you can find a few examples.

These include:

- win8-x86
- win10-x64
- win10-arm
- etc

This information has helped me structure a NuGet package that uses the runtimes folder, as I was struggling to know what the possible values were. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to have platform specific .NET Framework 4.5 assemblies in the package? Sort of runtimes\win7-x86\lib\net45. I tried to package assemblies in the aforementioned path but when consuming it VS/msbuild does not find the assembly.

Comment: I was able to get Visual Studio to use runtimes/win-x86/lib/net47, but not win7 or win10 variations of the same path.