# Where to find documentation of all supported nuget framework names

Tags: nuget

When building a nuget package with folder `lib\i-made-this-up\`, nuget Pack will output the following message:

```
The folder 'i-made-this-up' under 'lib' is not recognized 
as a valid framework name or a supported culture identifier.
```

Folder `lib\net40-wpf\` does not output this message so apparently it is a valid framework name. My questions is: how is `net40-wpf` defined? I expected it to be on this page but it isn't:
https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions

Do I miss something? Or is there a better source of documentation?

Comment: I think your question's off topic since you've implicitly asking for an off-site resource.

Answer (score 3):

You have the main documentation link for the NuGet target frameworks:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions

Unfortunately it is out of date and is missing newer target frameworks that NuGet supports.

A few more target frameworks are mentioned in the following blog post:

http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html

Currently the best place is the NuGet source code. For NuGet v2 the known target frameworks are defined in the VersionUtility class:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.8.6/src/Core/Utility/VersionUtility.cs

For NuGet 3 the list of target frameworks is defined in the FrameworkConstants class:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/FrameworkConstants.cs

NuGet 3 also has a set of [runtime identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699340/nuget-rid-and-tfm-examples) which are defined in a NuGet package so it is extensible.